# How can I zoom without moving camera (also for render)?

Tags: 3d-view, camera, image, tracking

I tried a tracking scene and I want to zoom in, kinda like the viewport zoom but for my final render.

Viewport Zoom, I want it to look like this in my render
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPI4I.jpg

But when animating the camera to get closer, or changing the focal length the background of course doesn't move along.

Example for focal length/camera animated zoom, background doesn't move along.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/An8iM.jpg

How can I do this?

(The gif file sizes were too big, I had to upload them elsewhere)

Answer (score 1):

That is a background image, it is not supposed to move. It's only for reference. If you want the image to stay in place, while you move the camera use the addon "import image as plane". Or simply create a plane with an emission material and use your BG image as the texture.

Comment: Thanks! The background is a video since I did a tracking setup. Does this also work for video backgrounds?

Comment: in theory it does, but you shouldn't zoom in 2D footage. You loose quality and it's very unnatural.

Answer (score 1):

Since the background scene looks fairly simple, I would just use projection mapping to create objects that have the background image as a texture. So I would have probably 4 different planes with texture projected on to them: horizontal one for the far left light grey tarmac, one for the darker tarmac in the center, one for the grass patch to the right and horizontal one for the stuff at the back. Then I would be able to manipulate the camera (to some extent) as the background would behave as expected.